# Which sql query is right in this case?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got table with sessions ([full table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eReefbzUI_UwNcnNBepvDSyOARE_7lNF/view?usp=sharing)).

|  | session_id | session_date_time | mentor_id | mentee_id | session_status | mentor_domain_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2021-02-12 00:00:00 | 30009 | 20136 | canceled | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-02-12 00:00:00 | 30032 | 20003 | finished | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-02-12 00:00:00 | 30020 | 20026 | finished | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 2021-02-12 00:00:00 | 30025 | 20006 | finished | 6 |
| 4 | 5 | 2021-02-12 00:00:00 | 30011 | 20006 | finished | 5 |
| 5 | 6 | 2021-02-13 00:00:00 | 30036 | 20056 | finished | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 2021-02-13 00:00:00 | 30015 | 20130 | canceled | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 2021-02-13 00:00:00 | 30009 | 20073 | finished | 7 |
| 8 | 9 | 2021-02-13 00:00:00 | 30010 | 20033 | finished | 5 |
| 9 | 10 | 2021-02-13 00:00:00 | 30004 | 20047 | finished | 5 |
| 10 | 11 | 2021-02-14 00:00:00 | 30004 | 20153 | finished | 6 |
| 11 | 12 | 2021-02-15 00:00:00 | 30015 | 20089 | canceled | 7 |
| 12 | 13 | 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 30046 | 20162 | finished | 6 |
| 13 | 14 | 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 30001 | 20012 | finished | 7 |
| 14 | 15 | 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 30025 | 20126 | finished | 3 |
| 15 | 16 | 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 30009 | 20118 | canceled | 7 |
| 16 | 17 | 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 30017 | 20098 | finished | 7 |
| 17 | 18 | 2021-02-18 00:00:00 | 30025 | 20112 | canceled | 6 |
| 18 | 19 | 2021-02-18 00:00:00 | 30004 | 20072 | finished | 5 |
| 19 | 20 | 2021-02-18 00:00:00 | 30004 | 20110 | finished | 5 |
| 20 | 21 | 2021-02-19 00:00:00 | 30015 | 20160 | canceled | 4 |
| 21 | 22 | 2021-02-20 00:00:00 | 30044 | 20164 | finished | 4 |
| 22 | 23 | 2021-02-20 00:00:00 | 30002 | 20031 | finished | 2 |
| 10417 | 10418 | 2022-09-15 00:00:00 | 30384 | 21802 | finished | 3 |
| 10418 | 10419 | 2022-09-15 00:00:00 | 30318 | 21837 | finished | 4 |
| 10419 | 10420 | 2022-09-15 00:00:00 | 30424 | 21842 | finished | 5 |
| 10420 | 10421 | 2022-09-15 00:00:00 | 30623 | 21591 | canceled | 6 |

I need to count mentees with canceled sessions only for every year.

My first query is:

```
select  date_trunc('year', session_date_time) as year_dt,
        count(distinct mentee_id) as mentee_can_ses,
        round((count(distinct mentee_id)-lag(count(distinct mentee_id)) over())*1.0/lag(count(distinct mentee_id)) over(), 2) as mentee_dynamic     
from    sessions as s
where   mentee_id not in (select distinct mentee_id from sessions as s where session_status = 'finished')
group by    date_trunc('year', session_date_time)
```

I thought that this is right query. I just get rid of mentee_id with finished sessions and get result: 2021 - 11 mentee, 2022 - 20 mentee.

But, later I make another query:

```
with table1 as (
    select  distinct mentee_id,
            date_trunc('year', session_date_time) as year_dt,
            count(session_id) filter(where session_status='finished') as ses_finished,
            count(session_id) filter(where session_status='canceled') as ses_canceled
    from        sessions as s
    group by    mentee_id, date_trunc('year', session_date_time)
    having  count(session_id) filter(where session_status='finished') = 0
)
select  year_dt,
        count(distinct mentee_id)
from        table1
group by    year_dt
```

And result of this query is different:
2021 - 102 mentee with canceled sessions only, 2022 - 37 mentees.

Which query is right and that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For clarity, you can use names instead of numbers for the `group by`: [Why do we use Group by 1 and Group by 1,2,3 in SQL query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86612/30172)

Comment: run explain query, so you see that they are not equal, the first only removes all finished rows and counts, the last looks if a mentee has ever had a finished, hadn't you made that strnge counting, you would have get more mentees

Comment: I get it. First query is wrong. Cause then I get rid of mentees with sessions I deleting mentee without checking dates. I literaly do not count mentee in 2022 year if he has at least one finished year in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

I give myself some time to rest and finally write good (at least better than my previous take) code.

```
select  date_trunc('year', s.session_date_time),
        count(distinct mentee_id) as all_cnt,
        count(distinct mentee_id) filter(where session_status = 'finished') as finished_cnt,
        count(distinct mentee_id) - count(distinct mentee_id) filter(where session_status = 'finished') as canceled_cnt
from    sessions as s
group by    date_trunc('year', s.session_date_time)
```